# Barcode creation in Jasper report: n is not a valid character for Standard 2 of 5 encoding

Tags: jasper-reports

Got the below error while i'm trying to create Barcode using Ireport 1.2.3

Error filling print...

> java.lang.RuntimeException: n is not a valid character for Standard 2 of 5 encoding
>       at it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage.getBarcodeImage(BcImage.java:73)
>       at PrintIDCardreport_1452662388727_145783.evaluate(PrintIDCardreport_1452662388727_145783:198)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:172)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:556)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:524)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:952)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:420)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:403)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:275)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:399)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:1289)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:631)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:228)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:750)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:666)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:601)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:517)
>       at it.businesslogic.ireport.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:680)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Code for barcode creation:

```
<image  scaleImage="FillFrame" vAlign="Middle" hAlign="Center" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
    <reportElement
        mode="Opaque"
        x="32"
        y="123"
        width="50"
        height="10"
        forecolor="#000000"
        backcolor="#FFFFFF"
        key="barcode-1"/>
        <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
        <graphicElement stretchType="NoStretch" pen="None" fill="Solid" />
<imageExpression class="java.awt.Image"><![CDATA[it.businesslogic.ireport.barcode.BcImage.getBarcodeImage(13,$F{subjectno1},false,false,null,0,0)]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Used jar files: barbecue-1.1.jar, ireport.jar.

I can able print barcode for static barcode expression.

Comment: We need to see the relevant part of you BcImage.getBarcodeImage, you error is not in jasper report but on this line BcImage.java:73, as this the question is not answerable.

Answer (score 1):

See the value of `$F{subjectno1}` variable for letters.

As stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleaved_2_of_5) 2 of 5 barcode standard is only for encoding digits. 
If You must have letters in it, check [code 128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) standard instead.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, no issue with code 128, able to print it but issue is with int2of5 even though $F{subjectno1} is int type field and data in it is 22.

Comment: Really, check the value of this field. :)

Also, You seem to use depreaced way of printing barcodes. See [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/539943/itbusinesslogicireportbarcodebcimage). If this will not help You, I am out of ideas. :)